# Function to describe a simple harmonic oscillator with asymmetric damping

Tags: mathematical-modeling, harmonic-functions, data-analysis

I have some data which looks like this:

[image]

i.e. initially oscillatory between $ \sim 0.8 - 1$, before tapering away.

Now I know that in general damped oscillations can be described by an exponential acting on the oscillations, e.g. $y(x) = A e^{-\lambda x} \sin \omega x$. A function of this form looks like this:

[image]

However, clearly this does not capture the full behaviour of the first figure. In particular, for the first figure the damping initially appears 'asymmetrical'. Can anyone suggest a function form that could capture the full behaviour?

Comment: @phdmba7of12 that is very helpful, thank you! What is $t$ here in the exponential? Do you mean $x$?

Comment: yes ... I meant $x$ ... I'll edit now to reflect that (couldn't edit ... had to delete and repost) :)

Comment: I think the equation for the above would better be written
$$ y(x) =B+ A e^{-\lambda x} \sin \omega x $$
because you have a DC offset (of around 0.8 in the diagram) ... this DC offset in the first diagram however seems be be decaying slowly ... so not only is the amplitude envelope decaying, the DC offset is as well ... perhaps an equation of the form $$ y(x) = Be^{-(x/\alpha)^\gamma}+A e^{-\lambda x} \sin \omega x $$
with $\alpha>0$ and $\gamma>0$ would work ... in particular with a $\gamma$ stretched exponential exponent greater than unity.